# Strange index behavior mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I usually pride myself to be a database pro but I can't really wrap my head around this behavior. I hope someone can explain how this is working.

I have two mysql tables orders:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `voucher_code` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
  `voucher_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `shipping_address_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `reference_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `reference_id` (`reference_id`),
  KEY `address_id` (`billing_address_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=168067 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE `addresses` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_addresses_users1_idx` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=95277 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now as you can see I have created an index inside the orders table for the `billing_address_id` called `address_id` that should match with the address `id`.

This is the query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT 
  o.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, o.total, o.date_created 
FROM 
  orders o USE INDEX FOR JOIN (PRIMARY) JOIN 
  addresses a ON a.id = o.billing_address_id 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

If I run the query without any index specification it will pickup and use the address_id index which I would expect be the fastest way to match the two tables.

Strangely enough with the 'address_id' index the query runs in 2 seconds.
If i use the normal 'PRIMARY' index which works on the order id it takes 0.000 seconds.

This is bugging me out. I thought I was supposed to create indexes to expedite the joining process between tables.

If I run EXPLAIN on the two queries I get:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT  o.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, o.total, o.date_created
    FROM  orders o
    JOIN  addresses a ON a.id = o.billing_address_id
    ORDER BY  id DESC
    LIMIT  0, 50 

1   SIMPLE  a   ALL PRIMARY             95234   100.00  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  o   ref address_id  address_id  4   my_basket.a.id  1   100.00
```

With the index:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT  o.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, o.total, o.date_created
    FROM  orders o USE INDEX FOR
    JOIN  (PRIMARY)
    JOIN  addresses a ON a.id = o.billing_address_id
    ORDER BY  id DESC
    LIMIT  0, 50 

1   SIMPLE  o   index       PRIMARY 4       50  332632.00   
1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   my_basket.o.billing_address_id  1   100.00
```

Thank you for finding the time to answer this question.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.6.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ORDER BY ... LIMIT queries it will often be beneficial to use a query execution plan that avoids sorting.  This is not necessarily because the sorting is expensive, but because it makes it possible to stop the query execution once the number of requested rows (here 50) are found.

In your case, if one starts with table a, the full join result will have to be generated before selecting the "top" 50 rows.  If you start with scanning table o using the PRIMARY index, the join result will be sorted on o.id, and the join execution can stop once 50 rows have been found.

The cost model used to select between the two approaches has been improved since MySQL 5.6.  I suggest you try out MySQL 5.7 to see if the MySQL optimizer is now able to select the most optimal plan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the two queries even compile -- `ORDER BY id` is ambiguous since each table has a *different* `id`.

When doing a `JOIN`, *always* qualify *all* columns.

Meanwhile, remove the `USE INDEX`.

Comment: Ok agreed it should be o.id however it complies ( probably due to the select fields ). The issue lays however with the INDEX itself. If i remove USE INDEX it goes much slower. What I dont understand is how can it run faster with the `order's id index` instead of the more logical `addresses id index` which is used by the join. 
**I guess the real explanation is that the most expensive operation here is the order by and not the join.**